# helm ls -a is giving "kubernetes cluster unreachable"

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Background: Something happened yesterday which led to usage of kubectl commands rendering my macbook unusable ( network/internet breaking and freezing all applications).

I fixed it by using

```
sriramkumar@Srirams-MacBook-Pro ~ % brew link --overwrite kubernetes-cli
```

Linking /usr/local/Cellar/kubernetes-cli/1.25.0... 224 symlinks created.

```
sriramkumar@Srirams-MacBook-Pro ~ % ls -al /usr/local/bin/kubectl       
lrwxr-xr-x  1 sriramkumar  admin  43  8 Sep 23:21 /usr/local/bin/kubectl -> ../Cellar/kubernetes-cli/1.25.0/bin/kubectl

And today I discovered it is helm that is broken, so eg. when I use `helm ls -a`
```

It is doing the exact same thing ( network/internet breaking and freezing all applications)

The error I'm getting is

```
sriramkumar@Srirams-MacBook-Pro ~ % helm ls -a
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://something.ibm.com:25628/version?timeout=32s": dial tcp: i/o timeout
```

I have uninstalled helm, reinstalled set `KUBECONFIG=/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml ( from the internet)` but it's not solving the issue. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Might be a certificate issue, so you can try removing the certificate-authority-data from the kubeconfig file and add insecure-skip-tls-verify: true in its place. Then try executing the helm command. If this works then you can try to fix the certificate-authority-data. Also try using any kubectl command to connect to the cluster, so you can identify the actual problem with kubeconfig file.